# Installation error of GeoPandas in PyCharm

Tags: python, installation, geopandas, error, pycharm

How can I install GeoPandas in PyCharm?
I tried to install GDAL first and GeoPandas but nothing works I'm getting installation failed error.
The error is 'installation failed you need visual studio to launch the application'

I'm posting a portion of the error :

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Silpa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uttajw_r\\fiona_de10274cb5c7486db63949e9e3b8e88c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Silpa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uttajw_r\\fiona_de10274cb5c7486db63949e9e3b8e88c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Silpa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-m3mdsra7'
         cwd: C:\Users\Silpa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uttajw_r\fiona_de10274cb5c7486db63949e9e3b8e88c\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
Building wheels for collected packages: fiona
  Building wheel for fiona (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fiona (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for fiona (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for fiona
Failed to build fiona
Installing collected packages: munch, cligj, click-plugins, shapely, pyproj, fiona, geopandas
    Running setup.py install for fiona: started
    Running setup.py install for fiona: finished with status 'error'
```

Is Visual Studio is needed to launch GeoPandas?
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: You don't install Geopandas or GDAL in Pycharm but in the Python version used by Pycharm

Comment: Including the error message (as formatted text, not a screenshot) would be very useful to people to help solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I ran into this issue last year some time, the following worked for me.

```
conda install fiona pyproj six
conda install geopandas
conda upgrade --all
```

Alternatively, you could try [the solution given in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635303/4227297)

> Thanks to the conda-forge community, geopandas is actually pretty easy to install on all platforms using the conda package manager (or: its dependencies, as this is the difficulty).
>
> If you have conda, it is just:
>
> `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to use pip install,  you can do one of the following listed on a similar stack exchange thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda).

I found success on Windows 11 with QGIS 3.26.1 added to path, with something similar but not listed on this thread:

Open cmd

```
py -m pip install pipwin 
py -m pipwin install fiona 
py -m pipwin install gdal 
py -m pip install geopandas
```

If you do not have QGIS added to path you will need to install the other dependencies listed in the GeoPandas [documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#dependencies) in a similar fashion.